# How to remove the Legend of chart from angular Chart.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I used the chart of my project, I used the angular chart.js. Legend but I don't want to use in my chart, I want to delete it. In the official document and did not find the relevant settings, and the Internet is not found to have the answer to the question, and hope to get everyone's help, thank you very much.

Comment: It's unclear what you are using is it angular-chart.js? http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ What's your code to display the chart now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chart-legend="false" to remove legend from chart.

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
  chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="false" chart-series="series">
</canvas>
```

The documentation already specify this in **settings** tab for all chart. Have a look at [this](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3te4hu7/1/) for both version(with/without legend)

Comment: Your answer has given me a lot of help. Thank you very much.